# How to Change WordPress Menu Structure (ul > li to nav > a)

Tags: php, wordpress, menu, menuitem

I'm trying to create a WordPress menu using:

```
        <?php 
            wp_nav_menu(
                array(
                    'menu' => 'Top Mid',
                    'container' => 'nav',
                    'container_class' => '',
                    'theme_location' => 'Top Mid',
                    'items_wrap' => '<ul>%3$s</ul>'
                )
            );
        ?>
```

The problem is that WordPress adding a ui > ul structure to the navigation whereas I want to use the following structure:

```
<nav>
   <a href="page1.html">Page 1</a>
   <a href="page2.html">Page 2</a>
   <a href="page3.html">Page 3</a>
   <a href="page4.html">Page 4</a>
</nav>
```

Any thoughts on how this can be implemented so that I can structure the menu with anything else than the unordered/ordered list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this function. This adds `<a>` tag.

```
$navItems = array(
  'container'       => false,
  'echo'            => false,
  'items_wrap'      => '%3$s',
  'depth'           => 0,
);

echo "<nav>";
echo strip_tags(wp_nav_menu($navItems), '<a>');
echo "</nav>";
```